# Why does EF Core auto generate null property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two models:

```
class ModelA 
{
    public Id {get; set;}
    public int? ModelBId { get; set; }
    public ModelB ModelB { get; set; }
}

class ModelB 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and when I try to add just ModelA (ModelBId is `int?`):

```
var model = new ModelA();
context.ModelAs.Add(model); // after this step ModelB is already set to not null
context.SaveChanges();
```

EF Core 2.2 inserts ModelA and ModelB... why? I just need to add ModelA with null ModelB... In EF6 it works...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: For sure EF isn't going to auto-create a `ModelB` object. It's something in code you don't show here, which is why a [mcve] is indispensable.

Answer (score -1):

Define you Foreign Key explicitly like this :

```
class ModelA 
{
    public Id {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("ModelB")]
    public int? ModelBId { get; set; }
    public ModelB ModelB { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
class ModelA 
{
    public Id {get; set;}
    public int? ModelBId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ModelBId")]
    public ModelB ModelB { get; set; }
}
```